# Convert types of column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have more than 80 tables in my SQL Server database. I have more than 500 column. I want change some types of columns to free the space.

I wrote this script just to see the column that beginner by `nvar` and `nch`.

```
WHILE (SELECT * 
       FROM DATA.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE (DATA_TYPE LIKE 'nvar%' OR DATA_TYPE LIKE 'nch%'))
       --OR DATA_TYPE LIKE 'float%')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'change type in SCHEMA';
END
```

I should add to this script or I write another to convert the types automatically.

Someone please can help me, how can I do it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Be aware that altering a column's type in any way that would actually free space (like reducing the size of a `CHAR` or `NCHAR` column) requires *more* space initially, as the whole table must be rebuilt in a transactional manner. Reducing the size of a `[N]VARCHAR` column is mostly pointless, as the size of the data on disk isn't changed. It just prevents people from storing larger values.

Comment: So what data type do you wish to change these data type too?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the columns you find. You say convert them; convert them to what?I don't really see it as a "good" idea to just change your data types. They should be that type for a reason. if you're making them smaller, you're risking truncation.

Comment: @MarkKram the type of the data is heterogeneous. But I want convert just the column that there type nvarchar and nchar to varchar and char

Comment: If you have Enterprise (or 2016 SP1, where it's available in all editions), consider using [data compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression) before reducing the ability of character columns to store Unicode data. You are likely to regret that decision later -- only in a handful of cases (like computer-generated codes) can you be sure your data will never be beyond the confines of an SQL Server code page.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert >>>only in a handful of cases (like computer-generated codes) can you be sure your data will never be beyond the confines of an SQL Server code page<<< Users of 1252 CP often don't need additional characters at all

Comment: @sepupic: I suppose one's mileage can vary. Analyzing the existing data to see if you already need Unicode would be a good indicator, as well as trying to anticipate if you're likely to ever, say, store text supplied by international customers. In either case, having to change columns to Unicode later if it ever does become necessary should, for most setups, be a bigger headache/concern than buying bigger disks now.

Comment: @vero, you also need to consider dependencies like indexes and constraints before changing the type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert , suppose I create one similar table with diff name and insert all data of old table.now drop old table.rename new table.if i follow this step for all then will I face problem like you mention ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh: if by "problem" you mean a space decrease, then yes. In all setups, the old and new data must coexist for a while, increasing the database size. Once the data has been changed the free space is available in the database, of course, but the file size will not decrease (unless you shrink it, which has its own, well-documented problems). There are workarounds for this using filegroups, but that's not exactly easy. In any case, "how do I rewrite a table while dealing with the space increase" should be (and probably is) its own question.

Comment: @Da Guzman thanks for your answer. I'll change them in local not yet I created indexes.  So how can I change the condition in the loop while to read all my tables in one SCHEMA and to convert all type of column from nvarchar to varchar or nchar to char ? Thank you

Comment: IMHO,you got lovely script below,if you want to go ALTER way.@JeroenMostert , I am talking of diff way to deal with "space increase issue".Like in this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190140/why-does-my-delete-command-require-huge-amount-of-temporary-run-storage/190375#190375.I can implement same logic here too.Will it help to solve "space increase issue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you considered the concerns raised by the commenters, this might be what you're looking for. The script will prepare SQL statements for your use, based on your referenced table's data.

Please double-check its correctness though. Also, I assumed you want new lines and `GO`'s, but you can easily remove those if you didn't want them.

```
SELECT
    AlterSql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' ALTER COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME, ' ', SUBSTRING(DATA_TYPE, 2, LEN(DATA_TYPE)), '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ') ', CASE IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'YES' THEN 'NULL' WHEN 'NO' THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'ERROR' END, CHAR(13), CHAR(10), 'GO')
  , *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your solution I should put each name of table and column, knowing that I have more 80 tables and more 500 column to convert them. and your solution will change the types of column just in a table INFORMATION_COLUMN not change them in there source tables. Is it possible to do it automatically for all the tables and to change there types in there source tables. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @vero, I think you misunderstood my code. This code does not modify anything in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or anywhere else, it is a `SELECT FROM` statement after all, and those cannot modify. What my code does is generate query text that you can use to update all your columns in one go. You just need to copy once the values of `AlterSql` and then paste them once into a query window, and then run the query once. This code does not require you to repeat something over and over.

Comment: One issue I noticed, is the `GO` part possibly causing a problem if your SSMS does not have the "*retain CR/LF*" option activated. Proper output should be `ALTER` coming at odd lines, and `GO` coming at even lines. If there seems to be a problem, try either disabling/removing the `GO` and newline parts, or [**enabling**](http://www.sqldiablo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Retain-CRLF.jpg) the SSMS option.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot @KtX2SkD. But why you repeated two times  : CHAR(13),
 CHAR(10) ? I think I should change it varchar.

Comment: @vero, I'm guessing you think those are data types. They are not. They are [**function calls**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql) to output [**ASCII characters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#Control_characters), specifically the CR(13) then LF(10), to insert a new line (*like we do by clicking ENTER*).

Comment: Ok good, but I don't unterstand where you changed nvarchar by varchar and nchar by char ?

Comment: When you run the query, then copy the contents of `AlterSql`, and paste that in a new empty window, and then run the contents you just pasted, it will change `nvarchar` and `nchar` to `varchar` and `char`. Each cell or row in `AlterSql` contain a script to change one column of one table. Check which cells or rows represent the columns or tables you want to modify, and copy-paste-run those.